# Analysis of ways to control/refresh a directive with isolated scope from parent controller

Tags: design, angularjs

I'm asking this question because there doesn't seem to be a "recommended" approach for this. 
If a page had a directive with isolated scope, and if the directive needs to update itself after an event triggered in the parent controller, there seem to be 3 ways to do this:

1. $watch an integer scope property in the directive; the parent controller would keep incrementing the property each time there's a need to refresh
2. $on / $broadcast an event from the controller and let the child directives subscribe to the event as applicable
3. Setup pub/sub via a service, the parent would publish, the directive would subscribe

I'm looking for any performance analysis of the above three approaches, and guidance on which should be used when. Also, I'm not sure why (3) would be required given that we already have (2).